# add data from custom table to order items

Tags: magento-1.9, orders

I have the following query running in a controller, that I use to retrieve orders:

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
   ->getCollection()
   ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
   ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc');
```

I need to add extra data from a custom table (shipping_dates) to each order's product and I'm doing the following (which works but it runs a query for each single product):

```
foreach($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item){             
     $query = 'SELECT * FROM shipping_dates where product_id = "'. $item->getProductId().'"';
     ...
     }
```

How can I avoid doing queries for each single product? So far I tried using left join w/o any success.